# How to start a Win32 GUI application as a background process?

Tags: c++, excel, winapi, com

When COM starts an out-of-process server via CoCreateInstance() with a CLSID derived from ProgId (eg "Excel.Application"), how exactly does this happen?

I can see entries in the Registry which give the command line:
[image]

When COM starts a new Excel server (if one is not already running), the `excel.exe` process is in the background (the lower part of the Task Manager window), and not accessible to the UI. I would like to replicate this.

I have tried this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string strApp{"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE"};
    string strParams{"/automation /x"};

    HINSTANCE hs = ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", strApp.c_str(), strParams.c_str(), NULL, SW_HIDE);
}
```

but up pops Excel in the foreground.

What Win32 API calls is COM making to start Excel in the background?

Comment: Why are you adding "/x"? IF you use a tool like Process Explorer you can see the exact command line the program was started with. Also, is there a reason you are using `ShellExecute()` instead of `CreateProcess()` ? `CreateProcess()` will return more useable information.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I am glad you asked me that! If I leave off the "/x" (the switch which forces Excel to start a new instance), then it activates an already-running Excel session: I don't want that. I used ShellExecute simply because it was simpler than trying to build the structure for CreateProcess that incorporates the SW_HIDE. Basically I am trying to access Excel as a 'private' server, that won't interfere with or be interfered by other user actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Command-line switches for Microsoft Office products](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Excel)

**/e** or **/embed**

Prevents the Excel startup screen from appearing and a new blank workbook from opening.

Example

excel.exe /e

Comment: That works as far as my needs so far. Many thanks. I saw this switch in the list and assumed it just hid the splash screen as well as avoiding a blank workbook. It replaces the  "/x". My plan is to launch Excel with my own xla as the startup file, which will open a new workbook with a specific name. I can then access that Workbook moniker from the ROT, and from there get the application object pointer.